# WPF Prism Region Transition

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, prism-4

I'm sorry this is a little vague, basically id like to animate my transition between views which are shown in my region manager - I've seen this in a few applications and it looks really slick!

So what I'm asking is - can anyone point me at any controls or tutorials for doing this?

cheers.
Ste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer;

The basic idea is to create or re-use a custom content control and animate use the visual state manager to animate the content based on.

Cheers.
Ste.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but for you nomads from the future, Sacha Barber has a cool region adapter that integrates with the Transitionals project.

Check it out here:

http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/prism-4-custom-transitioning-region/